# Apache RewriteRule in DirectoryMatch

Tags: apache, web-services, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a `<RewriteRule>` in a `<DirectoryMatch>` directive in order to do the following redirections:

`url/branch01/webservice/endpoint` => `/branch01/webservice/public/index.php`
`url/branch02/webservice/endpoint` => `/branch02/webservice/public/index.php`

Here is the tree structure:

```
/
├── branch01
|   ├── webservice
|       ├── public
|           ├── index.php
├── branch01
|   ├── webservice
|       ├── public
|           ├── index.php
...
```

My current setup is as below:

```
AliasMatch ^/(.*)/webservice/(.*)$ /$1/webservice/public/$2

<DirectoryMatch ^/.*/webservice/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule /webservice/public(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</DirectoryMatch>
```

But this is not working....

I can access the `index.php` file but the rewrite seems to be failing over.
Here are the logs I get from mod_rewrite:

```
(3) [perdir ^/.*/webservice/public/] add path info postfix: branch01/webservice/public/user -> /branch01/webservice/public/user/login

(3) [perdir ^/.*/webservice/public/] applying pattern '/webservice/public(.*)$' to uri '/branch01/webservice/public/user/login'

(4) [perdir ^/.*/webservice/public/] RewriteCond: input='branch01/webservice/public/user' pattern='!-f' => matched

(2) [perdir ^/.*/webservice/public/] rewrite '/branch01/webservice/public/user/login' -> 'index.php'

(3) [perdir ^/.*/webservice/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> ^/.*/webservice/public/index.php
```

I have a feeling it the last part of the logs that are failing as the .* is not being replaced by the real folder name but I am not sure

If there are any apache mod_rewrite expert out there, help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to make sure I understood: when user enters `www.example.com/something/webservice/anything`, you want to server him this: `www.example.com/something/webservice/public/index.php`?

Comment: That's correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even without `AliasMatch` or `DirectoryMatch`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/webservice/ $1/webservice/public/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @dusan.bajic unfortunately the rule does not even get hit (nothing in the logs)

Comment: Can you add `RewriteLog "path/to/rerwrite.log"` and `RewriteLogLevel 9` to .conf and restart apache, it should give us a hint what is going on